# Lost position after adding css change (jQuery)

Tags: css, hover, positioning

EDIT: I have gotten a fork to work with two brackets of code assigning the CSS corrently to the DOM, however it's not centered inside the parent div anymore. Any ideas?

jQUery:

```
$("#container").hover(function () {
$("#innerFocusPrompt").position({
    my: "center center",
    at: "center center",
    of: "#container"
});
$("#innerFocusPrompt").css({
    "display": "inherit"
}).fadeIn(100);
});
```

CSS:

```
#container {
background-color: black;
color: #121212;
height:400px;
width:400px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 50px;
}
#innerFocusPrompt {
display: none;
background-color: red;
color: black;
height:100px;
width:100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/7C2dc/1/

Comment: Still looking for help on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assiging `css` to `jQuery.position()` handler.

You can assign it to DOM like

```
$("#innerFocusPrompt").css({
    "display": "box"
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I had to end up doing that. However I lost my positioning, which is strange. See my update if you can offer more help.

Comment: Can't upvote just yet I guess. Thanks for the assistance. I'm not sure what you mean about the center alignment. It seems to want to be it's own block now instead of absolute positioning within the master.

Comment: Going to unaccept this answer and try to figure out the new problem.

Comment: @WASasquatch and what is it.?

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect.
You are trying to assign .css to position() of your element.

**Change your code to** :

```
$("#container").hover(function () {
   $("#innerFocusPrompt").position({
      my: "center center",
      at: "center center",
      of: "#container"
   });
   $("#innerFocusPrompt").css({
      "display": "box"
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I figured it was something like that. i got it work, and then ran into a new problem where I lost the positioning. :\

Comment: Thanks if you solve the current problem I'll change it to you, currently Mr Parmar did solve the original problem first. Not trying to cheat anyone.